# tmp file write pdf file google app engine django

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am using fpdf package for creating PDF in django. My file structure is

- project - contain all the setting files.
- apps -   contain all the apps folders like apps/account/views.py
  apps/profile/views.py
- static - static files
- templage - all the template
- tmp

  ```
   class PdfCreater(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       pdf = FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter')
       pdf.add_page()
       pdf.set_font('helvetica', 'BIU', 16)
       pdf.set_text_color(220,50,50)
       pdf.cell(100, 80, 'Hello World jaskaran singh!' )
       pdf.set_font('times', '', 12)
       pdf.cell(80, 10, 'Good Bye World!')
       path = str(settings.XYZ)

       pdf.output( path+ '/tmp/pdf_2.pdf')
       data = 'try' 

       return JsonResponse({"data": str(path), "header": data})
  ```

now i am wring this code but my pdf_2.pdf file is not create in tmp folder why?

In my localhost file has been create successfully but not in google app engine

getting this error

OSError at /converter/PdfCreater
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/workspace/tmp/pdf_2.pdf'

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-temp-files?tab=python

google app engine saying tmp folder you can write any thing but it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/runtimes), only the `/tmp` is in Read/Write access

Comment: can we do this with bucket ?

Comment: Is FPDF able to write directly to a bucket? with a path style `gs://`? not sure, but if it can, yes do it!